# Does a Series Voltage Reference referencing more than one electrical block has to be buffered?

Tags: amplifier, ldo, voltage-reference, summing

I'm planing to use a Series Voltage Reference,**REF3330**,  as a voltage reference to three distinct parts of my circuit and i need an opinion regarding the way how to do it. First of all, the reference provides a 3V reference voltage and the input voltage will be 3.3V. This agrees with the minimum supply conditions.

The circuits i want like to reference:
1) Reference of a single ended ADC embedded in PIC uC

2) A voltage divider of 10k-10k to reference an Inamp. (fig 1)

3) A summing configuration to DC bias an sinusoidal negative signal. (fig 2)

My question is do i need to buffer the output of the Voltage Reference ?  I have some doubts if i would win anything with it, first the voltage reference provides more than enough current to supply the three parts within its working limits. Second, has a very low output impedance (2ohms at 1kHz) so it wouldn't unbalance any of the voltage dividers.

Fig 1:
[image: Fig 1]

Fig 2:
[image: Fig 2]

Comment: The REF3330 is already buffered and can support +/- 5 mA sink/source. Unless you have high current requirements it should not need any buffering.

Comment: Damn it, how could i have missed it? Thank you very much for pointing it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With voltage references loading can become a concern, especially if accuracy is desired. Loading the voltage reference will sacrifice accuracy by a very small amount.

[image]

This probably doesn't apply to you since the load described above in the OP is about (a high impedance load like an opamp is negligible input current, I'll consider the sine input to be zero, and the micro ADC will also probably be less than 10uA, so I'll throw it out too) $$ \frac{3.3V}{20k+20k} = 0.082mA$$ so the error will be $$ \frac{20ppm}{mA}*0.082mA = 1.65ppm$$ not anything to worry about, unless the application was using a high accuracy ADC, just something to double check if you have a low error budget.

*Make sure* the capacitance loading is correct on the reference (it needs 0.1 to 10 uF) or the regulation will be poor.

So what the loading was an issue, what could you do? Put an op-amp buffer in between the voltage reference and the load.

Comment: Hey, thank you for so complete answer. I still have one question, i was looking to the output impedance and i see its variation with the frequency.  But i don't get it, this impedance is what my sine wave (1kHz) will see in Fig2. ? And in Fig1., the voltage divider is connected to an opamp and it will be connected to Ref Pin in a INamp, what is the frequency here, is DC ? Thank you.

Comment: The reference has an opamp in negative feedback, that means it controls the voltage but there are limits to how fast it can control. The reference controls to DC 3.3V in this case, but it can only do this so fast.  At 1kHz it means you could model the REF3330 as a voltage source with a a resistor in series ~5Ω, which will be nothing compared to the 20k load that you already have. (I'm having a hard time following the other questions, I think the datasheet I have is different from the one you have as fig2 is titled "temperature drift" on mine) If you like the answer upvote and mark answered